# Handling large list of lists in python

Tags: python, database, list, memory, python-itertools

I have this mathematical task in which I am supposed to find some combinations, etc. That doesn't matter, the problem is that I am trying to do it with itertools module and it worked fine on smaller combinations (6 - places), but now I want to do the same for large combination (18 - places) so here I run into problem because I only have 8GB of RAM and this list comes around 5GB and with my system running it consumes all RAM and then program drops MemoryError. So my question is: what would be good alternative to the method I'm using(code below)?

`poliedar_kom = list(itertools.combinations_with_replacement(range(0, 13), 18))
 poliedar_len = len(poliedar_kom)`

So when I have this list and it's length, the rest of program is going through every value in list and checking for condition with values in another smaller list. As I already said that's problem because this list gets too big for my PC, but I'm probably doing something wrong.

Note: I am using latest Python 3.8 64-bit

Summary: I have too big list of lists through which I have to loop to check values for conditions.

EDIT: I appreciate all answers, I have to try them now, if you have any new possible solution to the problem please post it.

EDIT 2: Thanks everyone, you helped me really much. I marked answer that pointed me to Youtube video because it made me realize that my code is already generator. Thanks everyone!!!

Comment: did you try to use generators? if you really only have to loop through the data, this might work

Comment: I am reading something on generators right now, and I think it might work because I managed to get that list saved to .txt file and every row is one value. Can you please point me somewhere where I could see an example for this, cause I never worked with these before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use generators for large data ranges, time and space complexity of the code will not increase exponentially with large data size, refer to the link for more details:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bD05uGo_sVI

Answer (score 0):

For any application requiring more than say, 1e4 items, you should refrain from using python lists, which are very memory- and processor-intesive

For such uses, I generally go to numpy arrays or pandas dataframes

If you aren't comfortable with these, is there some way you could refactor your algorithm so that you don't hold every value in memory at once, like with a generator?

Comment: Thank you for your response, I am not really expert in Python so if you could point me to some guides on how to use numpy arrays?

Comment: Numpy arrays are C-like data structures. a lot of their efficiency comes from the fact that you allocate the memory at initialization, and the size is thereafter immutable.  for more, this here's a beginner's guide: https://towardsdatascience.com/getting-started-with-numpy-59b22df56729

Answer (score 0):

in your case!

1) store this amount of data not in the RAM but inside a file or something in your HDD/SDD (say some SQL databases or NoSQL databases)

2) write a generator that processes each list (group of list for more efficiency) inside the whole list one after the other until the end

it will be good for you to use something like mongodb or mysql/mariadb/postgresql to store this amount of datas.